# Ionic back button with parent and child state

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, state

I have an ionic app with the following ui-router setup, where `locations` state is the parent of 2 states `map` and `favourites`. The `updates` state is a sort of *details* page that can be access from any state.

```
.state('locations', {
  abstract: false,
  cache: true,
  url: '/locations',
  templateUrl: 'templates/locations.html',
  controller: 'LocationsCtrl'
})
.state('locations.favourites', {
  cache: true,
  url: '/favourites',
  templateUrl: 'templates/locations.favourites.html',
  controller: 'LocationsFavouritesCtrl'
})
.state('locations.map', {
  cache: true,
  url: '/map',
  templateUrl: 'templates/locations.map.html',
  controller: 'LocationsMapCtrl'
})
.state('updates', {
  cache: true,
  url: '/updates/:place_id',
  templateUrl: 'templates/updates.html',
  controller: 'UpdatesCtrl',
  params: {'place_id': 'undefined'}
})


  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/locations/map');
```

This is the HTML

```
  <body ng-app="app" animation="slide-left-right-ios7">
<div>
    <div>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-turq">
            <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon icon ion-ios-arrow-back light"></ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works perfectly except that the back button on the "updates" state always goes back go `locations.map` rather than remembering the previous state, ie I might have come from `locations.favourites`. Is there something fundamentally wrong with my setup?

**

- UPDATE:

**

Okay so inside **UpdatesCtrl** I added this code to check the view history, and no matter where I access the **/updates** view from, the back view is **locations.map**

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
    console.log($ionicHistory.viewHistory());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this   params: {'place_id': 'undefined'} or make sure that you pass thru the place_id in $stateparams.place_id

I think that you are ending in an none unknown state (unresolved) and goes to your default state.

You haven't posted your default location route. But I'm assuming that it has this config: $urelRouterProvider.ohterwise('/location.map');

Comment: You're assumption is correct - I will try that and check. But I always pass athe place_id to "updates" state. The issue is going back from it.

Comment: Actually I tried changing the path of the otherwise state and it didnt make a difference. It always returns to the same point. One other interesting thing im experiencing is that the state of locations.map is never saved (or cached) so whenever i go to it it sort or loads from scratch